# Weblogic servers SSL issue on HTTPS

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, keystore, weblogic-10.x

I'm using weblogic 10.3.6 and I've deployed application A and B into the same box but different server instance.

Both servers are choosing 'Client Certs Not Requested' for the two way client cert behavior in SSL configurations.

Everytime we restart the servers, it was working fine on the same day. However from the next day onward, I am getting the following error when application A try to invoke a https server request to application B.

Weblogic server log trace:

```
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Filtering JSSE SSLSocket> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLIOContextTable.addContext(ctx): 455813> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <SSLSocket will  be Muxing> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <20666515 SSL Version 2 with no padding> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <21699288 SSL3/TLS MAC> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <21699288 received SSL_20_RECORD> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <HANDSHAKEMESSAGE: ClientHelloV2> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 58> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 4809> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <write HANDSHAKE, offset = 0, length = 4> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <isMuxerActivated: false> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <21699288 SSL3/TLS MAC> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <21699288 received ALERT> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <NEW ALERT with Severity: FATAL, Type: 46
    java.lang.Exception: New alert stack
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.alert.AlertHandler.handleAlertMessages(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.interpretContent(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.MessageInterpreter.decryptMessage(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.processRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.record.ReadHandler.readUntilHandshakeComplete(Unknown Source)
        at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.TLSConnectionImpl.completeHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at javax.net.ssl.impl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.server.channels.DynamicSSLListenThread$1.run(DynamicSSLListenThread.java:130)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
    > 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <Alert received from peer, notifying peer we received it: com.certicom.tls.record.alert.Alert@925980> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Warning> <Security> <BEA-090485> <CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN alert was received from serverB- 192.168.1.XXX. The peer has an unspecified issue with the certificate. SSL debug tracing should be enabled on the peer to determine what the issue is.> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <close(): 20666515> 
    <Apr 15, 2014 10:32:34 AM SGT> <Debug> <SecuritySSL> <BEA-000000> <close(): 20666515>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you use apache proxy (mod_weblogic), or you direct requests directly to weblogic server. If second option is true, you have to make sure you have proper certificates on server. All must be valid.

Also try to check/uncheck "Use JSSE SSL":

```
Domain -> Servers -> choose managed node -> Configuration -> SSL -> Advanced -> Use JSSE SSL
```

Comment: Hi Lubomir, thanks for your comment. My servers encountered SSL connection issue when i turn on Use JSSE SSL. Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: Hi Soosoo, most probably, there is some issue in your configuration try to google "weblogic JSSE SSL" keywords, to find out more.